# Redirect output to filename given by result of command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Suppose I have a file format I want to save database backups to given as such:

```
echo "~/backups/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql"
```

Now how can I specify this result as a filename for output in shell?

```
mysqldump my_db > ....?
```

<s>**By the way:** shell interprets the result of a nested echo command as an executable command/file. So</s>     It would seem that:

```
 mysqldump my_db > $(echo "something")
```

does NOT work. Instead, shell looks for a file called `something` and tries executing it?

Comment: The "by the way" part is simply not true.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to use nested echo. You can avoid it:

```
mysqldump my_db > ~/backups/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql
```

Answer (score -1):

$(echo "something") is not the problem, while ~ is.
It works fine if you use full path:

```
echo 'hello world' > $(echo "/home/root/backups/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql")
```

In case you're interested in how to use ~:

```
eval "echo 'hello world' > $(echo "~/backups/$(date +'%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S').sql")"
```

Comment: Not really... bash redirect can handle `~`; no need to convert `~` to `/home/root/`; unless, it is being run by some other user or from a non-interactive way...

Comment: Really don't perpetrate [useless use of `echo`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo)

Answer (score -1):

I think there are more possibilities to answer this question:
[How to name a file with current time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54054496/how-to-name-a-file-with-current-time)  [duplicate]

--

You can create a file in bash by using different utilities

*Using touch*

```
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# touch $(date +"%T") //you can format time as per your need
```

*Using editor*

```
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# vi $(date +"%T")
```

*Using redirection*

```
root@ubuntu:~/T/e/s/t# echo "Input for file" > $(date +"%T")
```

**Time format**

In place of `%T` you can use your own time format
  Refer: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/time.1.html

Comment: The question asks specifically how to redirect. The parts of this answer which do not duplicate the accepted answer are simply not pertinent here.

Comment: I specifically mentioned this question in the headline: How to name a file with current time? [duplicate]

Because you mentioned the question as a duplicate of this one and I'm not able to comment on that page.