# How to name a file with current time?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to create a file using bash that has the current time as it's name. This is how I'm trying to do it:

`echo 'hello' > date +"%T".txt`

What am I missing?

Comment: `echo 'hello' > $(date +"%T").txt`

Comment: The expression after `>` is essentially a string. Use a command substitution to make that string be the output of a command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use command substitution to capture `date`'s output as a string.

```
echo 'hello' > "$(date +%T)".txt
```